# regex for email validation (minimum characters)

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regular expression for email validation in javascript so that,characters before '@' should have minimum length of 5(those characters can be any between A-Z/a-z/0-9_-)

> Example: Sr_369@gmail.com

Comment: That's a very odd set of restrictions that will disallow many, many real email addresses. (It's also fairly easy—presumably you've read a regex tutorial or two—what have you tried? How does what it does differ from what you want?)

Comment: Best regex to validate **all** emails: `/[^@]+@[^@]/`

Comment: @elclanrs There should at least be one dot in it after the @

Comment: @flec: Not necessarily altough it's very rare. Take a look at "Valid email addresses" here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question the regex would be

```
/^[\w-]{5,}@.*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this site for regular expressions

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email

and to use it with JavaScript

```
function emailValidation()
{
var emailRegEx =/^([a-zA-Z0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*([\._-])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+(\.))+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/

if (document.testForm.textBox.value.search(emailRegEx )==-1) //if match failed
{
alert("invalid Email!!!");
}
else
{
alert("valid Email.");
}
}
```

Comment: even `space` and many other chars are valid...better stick with `.*@.*`..

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Space and several odd characters (even `@` is valid in local part) are valid, but they need to be quoted. People rarely use those kinds of emails, though. Looking at all the email validation answers on SO, weird emails will be rejected by quite a large number of them.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes you are right..wonder why those special chars are valid at the first place..;)